# Change zero values in MATLAB table to empty value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a table in which the first row entries are characters and the following row entries are double values. Now I want to *replace all zero values of the table with [] without using a for loop*. I tried:

```
A([false(size(A),1) (A{:,2:size(A,2)} == 0)]) = [];
```

But the usage of a logical matrix with the same size of A does not work.
Can anybody provide me a elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: MATLAB doesn't like Swiss Cheese, so you can't just poke holes in matrices. Whether this can be done with a table I'm not sure; are you looking for something akin to a sparse matrix, or truly a table as e.g. `[4, 5, []; 2, 7, 9]`?

Comment: @Adriaan Funny because I'm Swiss :) Truly a table as in your example.

Comment: instead of [] -> you could make the entries NaN

Comment: @matlabgui The right side of the equal sign is not the issue, since A([false(size(A),1) (A{:,2:size(A,2)} == 0)]) already doesn't work.

Comment: If you table is all numeric, you could convert the table to a matrix, do the 1 line operation on that with the logical index and then convert it back to a table -> but I certainly wouldn't call that elegant....  Provide an [minimal example with data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)